# ¿Como realizar un menu en Hibernate+ jsf + primefaces?

Tags: java, hibernate

Acabo de editar la pregunta. 
Bueno yo ya lo realize el menu pero sin hibernate mejor dicho con jdbc.
pero al momento de desplegar el proyecto no me muestra el menu con hibernate voy a dejar las tablas. [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy trabajando con netbeans y al momento de realizar con hibernate me generan las clases en paquete modelo.

ahora en el dao.

public interface relacionDao {
    public List listarRelacion();
}

en el daoImpl

public class relacionDaoImpl implements relacionDao {

```
@Override
public List<Relacion> listarRelacion() {
   List<Relacion> lista=null;
   Session session=HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
   Transaction t=session.beginTransaction();
    String hql="From Relacion";
    try{
        lista=session.createQuery(hql).list();
        t.commit();
        session.close();
    }catch(Exception e){
        t.rollback();
    }
    return lista;
}
```

en el bean.

@Named
//@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class relacionBean implements Serializable {

```
private List<Relacion> lista;
private Relacion relacion = new Relacion();
private MenuModel model;
private relacionDaoImpl relaciondao = new relacionDaoImpl();

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    this.listarMenus();
    model = new DefaultMenuModel();
    this.establecerPermisos();
}

public void listarMenus() {

    try {
        lista = relaciondao.listarRelacion();
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
}

public MenuModel getModel() {
    return model;
}

public void setModel(MenuModel model) {
    this.model = model;
}

public void establecerPermisos() {
    Empleado lg = (Empleado) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSessionMap().get("empleado");
    for (Relacion m : lista) {
        if (!m.getSubmenu().isProcesado()) {
            int actual = m.getSubmenu().getMenu().getIdMenu();

            if (m.getSubmenu().getMenu().getTipo().equals("S") && m.getEmpleado().getCodEmpleado() == lg.getCodEmpleado()) {
                DefaultSubMenu firstSubMenu = new DefaultSubMenu(m.getSubmenu().getMenu().getNomMenu());

                for (Relacion i : lista) {

                    if (actual == i.getSubmenu().getMenu().getIdMenu() && !i.getSubmenu().isProcesado()) {
                        Submenu submenu = i.getSubmenu();
                        Empleado empleado = i.getEmpleado();
                        if (submenu != null) {
                            if (submenu.getMenu().getIdMenu() == m.getSubmenu().getMenu().getIdMenu() && empleado.getCodEmpleado() == m.getEmpleado().getCodEmpleado()) {
                                DefaultMenuItem item = new DefaultMenuItem(i.getSubmenu().getNombreSubMenu());
                                item.setUrl(i.getSubmenu().getLinkSubMenu());
                                firstSubMenu.addElement(item);
                                i.getSubmenu().setProcesado(true);
                            }

                        }

                    }
                }
                model.addElement(firstSubMenu);
                m.getSubmenu().setProcesado(true);

            } else if (m.getSubmenu().getMenu().getIdMenu() != m.getSubmenu().getIdSubMenu() && m.getEmpleado().getCodEmpleado() == lg.getCodEmpleado()) {
                DefaultMenuItem item = new DefaultMenuItem(m.getSubmenu().getMenu().getNomMenu());
                item.setUrl(m.getSubmenu().getLinkSubMenu());
                model.addElement(item);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

en la plantilla xhtml.

Facelets Template

```
<h:body>

    <div id="top" >
        <ui:insert name="top">
            <h:form>
                <p:menubar model="#{relacionBean.model}"/>


            </h:form>

        </ui:insert>
    </div>

    <div id="content" class="center_content">
        <ui:insert name="content">Content</ui:insert>
    </div>

    <div id="bottom">
        <ui:insert name="bottom">Bottom</ui:insert>
    </div>

</h:body>
```

realizando el despliegue no me muestra el menú. pero cuando lo realizo con JDBC si me genera el menú espero me disculpen pero un poco que no entiendo hibernate muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1):

No se puede portar el código que has puesto simplemente porque no sabemos como son tus entidades. Sin embargo, básicamente en Hibernate/JPA se trabaja así.

- Cada clase debe estar anotada con `@Entity` o estar listada en la unidad de persistencia (`persistence.xml`).
- Toda entidad debe tener un campo anotado con `@Id`, el cual representa la llave primaria.
- Las relaciones entre entidades se realizan mediante `@OneToOne`, `@OneToMany` y `@ManyToMany`.
- Las entidades deben implementar la interface `Serializable`.

**Ejemplo**

```
@Entity
public class Order implements Serializable {

    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "order_id")
    private Long id;
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date date;
    private double amount;
    @OneToMany
    @JoinTable(
        name = "order_order_details",
        inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name = "order_detail_id"),
        joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name = "order_id")
    )
    private List<OrderDetail> details;

    // constructor, getters y setters
}
```

La entidad `OrderDetail` contiene los productos y la cantidad solicitada.

```
@Entity
public class OrderDetail implements Serializable {

    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "order_detail_id")
    private Long id;
    @OneToOne
    private Product product;
    private short quantity;

    // constructores, getters y setters
}
```

La entidad `Producto` se puede deducir.

**Tip:** En Hibernate/JPA hay un concepto llamado `fetch type` o **tipo de obtención**, el cual indica **en qué manera queremos obtener las relaciones**. Hay 2 tipos:

- Eager(FetchType.EAGER): las relaciones se obtendrán junto con la entidad principal. Supongamos que obtienes una orden, entonces en ese mismo momento se trae junto con ella la lista de detalles.
- Lazy(FetchType.LAZY): las relaciones se traen **solo cuando se obtienen explícitamente** por medio del getter.

Si una orden tiene muchos detalles es mejor hacer esa relación tardía.

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
```

En tu código veo una **cantidad considerable** de `Joins` haciendo el código poco legible. Con Hibernate/JPA todo esto se hace internamente. Para obtener una orden con su detalle, basta con llamar al getter, así:

```
Order order = em.find(4359L, Order.class);
List<OrderDetail> details = order.getDetails();

// Imprime el producto y la cantidad de cada detalle 
details.stream().forEach(System.out::println);
```

**Tip:** puedes ver las consultas que crea Hibernate si añades las siguientes líneas al `persistence.xml`:

```
<property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
<property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
```

Como puedes ver, JPA/Hibernate te abstrae de muchas tareas con la base de datos, como cualquier ORM. Sin embargo, no todo proyecto justifica usar un ORM; se debe tener en cuenta lo siguiente:

- Necesidad de alto rendimiento
- Complejidad del esquema

Si necesitamos alto rendimiento, lo mejor será usar alguna librería ligera como [jOOQ](http://jooq.org) o JDBC plano. Si nuestro proyecto es pequeño, entonces no justifica usar un ORM.

Comment: Implementar `java.io.Serializable` es *opcional* y sólo es requerido en un caso muy particular.

Comment: Así es, @PaulVargas. De acorde con la especificación oficial, hay dos escenarios. Cuando es pasado a como `detached` (por ejemplo a través de un EJB remoto, RMI) o si se usa consultas nativas, que el 95% en un proyecto real, sucede así.

Comment: PD: Si quieres añadir información, publica tu respuesta.

Comment: Si consigo algo de tiempo, tal vez agregue una repuesta con referencias. Mientras tanto, ejecutaré algunas *consultas nativas*, aunque ahora tengo que implementar `java.io.Serializable`.

Comment: Lo que usted diga, *ultra ultimate master developer*.